# How to take a state from the browser history, restore it and push it as a new state?

Tags: javascript, html, click, href, html5-history

In the following explanation, pages are represented by letters A,B,C,... and the current page is represented by a bold letter.

When the user navigated to **D**, the history is like follows:

A, B, C, **D** . Clicking C on my navigation bar should cause history.back() or history.go(-1) in order to call the previous state C. 
Then, I want my history to look like this:
A,B,C,D,**C**. So it should be the *real* history the user produced one after one.
But going back with `history.back()` causes the history: A,B,**C**.
Going back with `history.go(-1)` causes the history A,B,**C**,D (and the forward button leads to D).

How can I take the state like: `var againstate=history.previousState`
and do `history.pushState(againstate)` and go to that state?

Or any recommendations for other approaches?